# SharePoint online and SharePoint web hosting

Tags: sharepoint-online

I checked a hosting company like apps4rent that host SharePoint 2016 and the Microsoft that provide SharePoint online, I want to know What is the difference between SharePoint online and SharePoint web hosting? and advantages of each one over the other.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-on-premises-vs-sharepoint-online) great article :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to be able to define the difference, you should first know what's the Web hosting and Cloud hosting:

**What's the Web hosting?**

Web hosting is the business of providing server space, web services and file maintenance for websites controlled by companies or individuals that do not have their own web servers. for more details check [What is web hosting?](http://ragingcreations.com/pages/what-is-the-difference-between-web-hosting-and-cloud-computing.html)

Web hosting comes mainly in two types,

- **Dedicated.**

  - a company pays for the complete resources of one or more servers from a service provider. The client has a set amount of dedicated bandwidth, CPU, RAM, and drive space, and the client has full control over the server's resources.
- **Shared.**

  - a company pays for a set amount of space (storage) on a single server, and that server’s resources are shared by a number of other websites. It’s a cost-efficient, low-maintenance way to host a website or application, and the hosting company is responsible for managing, maintaining, and updating the units.

And based on what's the type of web hosting you would pay, you will be able to host your SharePoint solution over the internet.That mean you have **SharePoint On-prem**  hosted **outside** your physical servers. specifically, at the service provider (like GoDaddy) servers.

on the other side, the SharePoint online is **software as a service** based on the **cloud**.

**So what's the cloud hosting?**

Cloud hosting provides virtual space on an on-demand, as-needed basis. Instead of paying for a set amount of space on a single server, the client pays as they go for what they actually use.

There are also different types of cloud

- **Software as a Service (SaaS):**

  - SaaS is the most popular and widely used form of the cloud. It provides all the functions of a complicated traditional application. But instead of making use of a locally installed application, these functions are provided through a web browser.
- **Platform as a Service (PaaS):**

  - This type of cloud provides virtualized servers where users can run existing applications or develop new ones without worrying about the maintenance of the operating systems, server hardware, computing capacity or load balancing.
- **Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS):**

  - This type of cloud provides virtualized servers, networks, storage, and systems software designed to add to or replace the functions of an entire data center.

For more details about the difference between cloud hosting and the web hosting check [CLOUD HOSTING VS. TRADITIONAL HOSTING](http://www.opusinteractive.com/cloud-hosting-vs-traditional-hosting/#) and [Cloud Computing Vs web hosting?](http://ragingcreations.com/pages/what-is-the-difference-between-web-hosting-and-cloud-computing.html)

Now let's come back to answer your question:

**What is the difference between SharePoint online and SharePoint web hosting?**

There are three main factors you should care about them.

- **Cost**. depend on your space requirements and the number of users so you can compare between [SharePoint online plan](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans) and the web hosting companies quotas.
- **Scalability**. the SharePoint online is scalable than SharePoint web hosting. in SharePoint online, you pay for a software as a service and what actually you need and use.
- **Functionality**. I think you should now compare between SharePoint online and SharePoint on-prem rather than the hosting type so please check the technical comparison between SharePoint online and SharePoint on-prem at [SharePoint On – Premises VS. SharePoint Online](https://www.cloudally.com/sharepoint-on-premises-vs-sharepoint-online-2013/)